# Explain why the number of integer solutions is equal to the number of integer partitions of $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

I have to explain how the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + \dots + nx_n = n$ with $x_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1,2,\dots,n $ is equal to the number of integer partition of $n$.

I made an attempt. Assume $x_1 = a_1, x_2 = a_2, \dots , x_n = a_n$ Then we have a partition of $n$ equal to $a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3 + \dots + na_n = n$

$$\Rightarrow  (1 + 1 + \cdots + 1) + (2 + 2 + \cdots + 2) + \cdots + (n + n + \cdots + n) = n$$

Got up this point, but I don't know what to do next. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A partition of $n$ is completely specified when we know the number of parts of each size. For instance, the partition $2+2+2+1+1$ of $8$ is completely specified by saying that it has $3$ parts of $2$ and $2$ parts of $1$. Interpret the numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ as numbers of parts in some way. I’ve put a further hint in the spoiler-protected box below.

> $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$ is the total number of parts in the partition corresponding to that solution to the equation.

**Added:** Here is an example to illustrate more fully the correspondence between solutions in non-negative integers to $$1x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\ldots+nx_n$$ and partitions of $n$. Specifically, I’ll match each of the $7$ partitions of $5$ with the corresponding solution to $1x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5=5$.

$$\begin{align*}
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}5:\\
&1\cdot0+2\cdot 0+3\cdot0+4\cdot0+\color{blue}{5\cdot 1}=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_5=1};x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{4+1}\\
&\color{blue}{1\cdot1}+2\cdot 0+3\cdot0+\color{blue}{4\cdot1}+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_4=1,x_1=1};x_2=x_3=x_5=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{3+2}\\
&1\cdot0+\color{blue}{2\cdot1}+\color{blue}{3\cdot1}+4\cdot0+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_3=1,x_2=1};x_1=x_4=x_5=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{3+1+1}\\
&\color{blue}{1\cdot2}+2\cdot0+\color{blue}{3\cdot1}+4\cdot0+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_3=1,x_1=2};x_2=x_4=x_5=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{2+2+1}\\
&\color{blue}{1\cdot1}+\color{blue}{2\cdot2}+3\cdot0+4\cdot0+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_2=2,x_1=1};x_3=x_4=x_5=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{2+1+1+1}\\
&\color{blue}{1\cdot3}+\color{blue}{2\cdot1}+3\cdot0+4\cdot0+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_2=1,x_1=3};x_3=x_4=x_5=0\\
&\\
&\color{red}5=\color{blue}{1+1+1+1+1}\\
&\color{blue}{1\cdot5}+2\cdot0+3\cdot0+4\cdot0+5\cdot0=\color{red}5\\
&\color{blue}{x_1=5};x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The case 4 + 1 of 5 has 1 part for 1 and 1 part for 4. How do we apply this?

Comment: @Min: Follow the hint: two of the numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ should be $1$. Which two?

Comment: Ohh, it got it. Sorry, i am just over complicating things. To explain this question may i answer: A partition of a positive integer n is a multiset of positive integers that sum to n. Here, $x_1  to  x_n$ are parts that sum up to n and the number of ways these combinations can create n is equal to partition of n. As $x_i$ is larger or equal to 0, we can leave the untouched x equal to 0 and create any n possible.

Comment: For instance, number 5 has 7 partitions and they are 5, 4 + 1, 2 + 3, 3 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2 + 1, 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, and 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1. The partition 5 of 5 has 1 part of 5 and 0 part for other numbers. Therefore $5 = 0 + 2*0 + 3*0 + 4*0 + 5*1. Apply the same method to other cases, the number of solutions we get will be equal to the partition of n. Is this a good enough explanation? I am not too good with them so need more work on it

Comment: @Min: Your example with the partition $5$ of $5$ is correct, but what you’ve said before it isn’t right: $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are **not** the parts that sum to $n$. The parts are actually the coefficients $1,2,\ldots,n$ in the equation $$1\cdot x_1+2x_2+\ldots+nx_n=n\,;$$ each $x_k$ is the *number* of parts of size $k$ in a given partition. To answer the question you have to give a bijection between solutions to the equation and partitions of $n$. For instance, the solution $x_2=1$, $x_3=2$, $x_5=3$, and $x_1=x_4=x_6=\ldots=x_{23}=0$ when $n=23$ corresponds to what partition of $23$?

Comment: @Min: That makes no sense: what you’ve written **isn’t** a partition of $n$. I really think that until you can answer the question in my last comment, you aren’t going to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: @Min: Unfortunately, there’s not much more that I can say without simply doing the problem. Does it help at all if I say that the partition of $23$ in my question in the comment before last is $$23=\underbrace{5+5+5}_3+\underbrace{3+3}_2+\underbrace{2}_1\,?$$

Comment: I can see that the coefficient of $x_i$ is increasing just like the given function $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 23$ where $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 5$. The example does help me to understand the question but i just dont know how to prove it.

Comment: @Min: No. That partition corresponds to the solution $$1\cdot0+2\cdot1+3\cdot2+4\cdot0+5\cdot3+6\cdot0+7\cdot0+\ldots+23\cdot0=23$$ to the equation $$1\cdot x_1+2\cdot x_2+3\cdot x_3+\ldots+23\cdot x_{23}=23\,.$$ Look at the non-zero terms: $2\cdot 1+3\cdot 2+5\cdot 3=23$. And I’m telling you that this solution should be associated with the partition in my previous comment.

Comment: To prove for bijective, we need to prove for injective and surjective. Prove injective by contradiction. Assume $a_1 + 2a_2 + ... + na_n \neq b_1 + 2b_2 + ... + nb_n$. but the partition of both side $n_1 and n_2$ are equal. By our assumption $n_1 = n_2$, this implies that both side have the same number of partitions. This would mean $a_1 + 2a_2 + ... + na_n = b_1 + 2b_2 + ... + nb_n$, contradicting our initial assumption that $a_1 + 2a_2 + ... + na_n \neq b_1 + 2b_2 + ... + nb_n$. I am trying to give a bijection between solutions to the equation and partitions of n

Comment: @Min: Oh, dear. You cannot prove anything until you actually specify what the bijection is. You have to be able to say, for instance, exactly what solution to $$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\ldots+10x_{10}=10$$ corresponds to the partition $10=3+2+2+2+1$, and what solution corresponds to the partition $10=6+2+1+1$, and so on: the specific values of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{10}$. I’ve given you one example, for $n=23$.

Comment: I don't think I can solve this question. Can you give me the solution please? I can use it to study. This is too hard for me.